# How do I view all the attributes of a backbone.js model?

Tags: backbone.js

Is there an easy way to view all the attributes of a backbone.js model that I could access with @model.get()? `alert @model.attributes` only displays [object Object].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just the keys for the attributes, try:

```
Object.keys(@model.attributes)
```